# Lisp/Scheme interpreter without Emacs?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I've been wanting to teach myself Lisp for a while.  However, all the interpreters of which I've heard involve some flavor of emacs.
Are there any command line interpreters, such that I could type this into the command line:

> lispinterpret sourcefile.lisp

just like I can run perl or python.

While I'd also like to become more familiar with Emacs (if only not to be frustrated when I work with somebody who uses Emacs), I'd rather decouple learning Emacs from learning Lisp.

Edit: I actually want to follow SICP which uses Scheme, so an answer about Scheme would be more useful.  I'm just not that familiar with the differences.

Answer (score 13):

You could also try [DrScheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/), which whilst not exactly a standalone interpreter, isn't emacs :)

It's basically a simple IDE that has an area to type in code that can be executed as a file, and then another area that is the running interpreter that you can interact with.

(Also, find the UC Berkeley CS61A podcasts and listen to them, as well as reading SICP)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL) also caters to what you want:

http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Shebang-Scripts

SBCL is both top rate and open source.

Answer (score 6):

Checkout CLISP [wiki-link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLISP) that ie. was used by Paul Graham

Direct [link](http://clisp.cons.org/)

Comment: clisp is specially good for interactive use when compiled with ncurses support (TAB-completion bash style) fetching of documentation from hyperspec, etc.

Comment: If with "ie." you mean "i.e.": that says "id est" (in english: "that is").  I think that you want to say "e.g." (exempli gratia = for example).

Answer (score 5):

I often write lisp shell scripts which start with this line:

#!/usr/bin/clisp

Then you don't even need to type "lispinterpret" on the command-line.  Just mark the script executable and run it directly.

Answer (score 4):

Most scheme interpreters that I am familiar with can be run from the command line.  (Much of the list below is extracted from the comparative table at Alexey Radul's [Scheme Implementation Choices](http://web.mit.edu/~axch/www/scheme/choices.html) page.  There is a more extensive list at [schemewiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations) but that page does not immediately provide command-line invocation syntax.)

Here's how you run a number of implementations at the command line:

- [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/): `scheme`, `petite`
- [MIT Scheme](http://swiss.csail.mit.edu/projects/scheme/): `mit-scheme`
- [Scheme 48](http://s48.org/): `scheme48`
- [RScheme](http://www.rscheme.org/): `rs`
- [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/): `racket` (But I recommend trying the DrRacket IDE, especially for beginners.)
- [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html): `guile`
- [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/): `bigloo`
- [Chicken](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/): `csi`
- [Gambit](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page): `gsi`
- [Gauche](http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/): `gosh`
- [IronScheme](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/): `IronScheme.Console`
- [Kawa](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/): `kawa`, `java kawa.repl`
- [Larceny](http://www.larcenists.org/): `larceny`
- [SCM](http://swissnet.ai.mit.edu/~jaffer/SCM.html): `scm`

Comment: Sometimes these repls have very bad "line editing". Hitting the left arrow and getting ^[[D is awful. For those cases, you can use rlwrap, which wraps the program with read line support (run it with `rlwrap <commandrepl>`). Your readline settings (~/.inputrc file) will take effect, so you can even use readline's vi mode if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for Scheme to work with the SICP, take a look at MIT/GNU Scheme

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/

http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/index.html

Comment: MIT/GNU Scheme uses an interpreter that is pretty much like Emacs.

Comment: The included Edwin editor is like Emacs and the REPL has some Emacs-like commands for [interrupting](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Interrupting.html#Interrupting), but that is not everything. With MIT-Scheme, he *could* learn Scheme without learning Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

The most widely used IDE for Common Lisp, particularly in the free software subset of the community, is in fact [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), which runs on Emacs. You can use whatever CL compiler you prefer and invoke Lisp source files the way you describe, but if you do that, you won't be taking advantage of many of Lisps dynamic features that are so incredibly useful while developing your application.

I suggest you take a look at this [SLIME demonstration video](http://common-lisp.net/project/movies/movies/slime.mov) to see what I mean, even though it might be a bit outdated at this point.

If the problem is that you (think you) don't like Emacs, I seriously suggest you try to learn it. Seriously. No, really, I mean that. However, there are alternatives, such as the IDEs provided by commercial Lisp implementations such as [Allegro](http://www.franz.com/products/allegrocl/) and [Lispworks](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html) (free trials available), or an Eclipse plug-in called [Cusp](http://bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Allegro CL from http://www.franz.com/?

Comment: @crashmstr: Allegro has a free trial version that should be entirely adequate if you want to learn that language.

Answer (score 1):

@Nathan: I've upmodded the Common Lisp links, because you asked about Lisp (especially with reference to Emacs Lisp). However, Common Lisp is very different from Scheme. A program written for one is unlikely to run on the other.

As you mentioned, SICP is for learning Scheme, not Lisp (or at least, not Common Lisp and not Emacs Lisp). There are some overlap in principles, however you can't simply cut and paste code from SICP and expect it to run on any Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp system. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No "interpreter" requires emacs.

Also, emacs can run elisp in a headless manner.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like scheme shell is suitable for your purpose.
Take a look at http://www.scsh.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Another good dialect of lisp is [cmucl](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cons.org%2Fcmucl%2F&ei=04CjSMesMIKWsAPkreiEDw&usg=AFQjCNEaD4T5bkSLBKWylon98jBsL7-IGA&sig2=W3p2EItQZ4NdWN8YCzPbRg).  They used to love to brag about being the "fastest" lisp.