# Can I Easily Use Lisp Without Emacs?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm currently reading Practical Common Lisp.  The book is great and the language interesting, but I'm not enamored of learning Emacs.  I've learned Vim and that's enough text-mode editors for one brain.  I don't want to learn another.  Double-control commands hurt my head.  What's the best non-Emacs solution for programming Lisp on Windows?

Comment: Check out stack overflow question ["lispscheme-interptreter-without-emacs"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650/lispscheme-interptreter-without-emacs )

Answer (score 7):

Best free and non-emacs Common Lisp IDE is [CUSP](http://www.bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/) (IDE for Lisp built on Eclipse platform).

Comment: I've tried cusp several times and have always had difficulty getting it to actually talk to SBCL.

Answer (score 6):

Try [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Try [viper-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode), perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

Limp for Vim.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2219

Answer (score 1):

Try Slime for Vim: http://technotales.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/like-slime-for-vim/ . Works great!

You could also use the Allegro CL environment.